# Why can't ruby (in Travis CI) find my bundle installed gems?

Tags: ruby, bundler, travis-ci

I'm trying to set up Travis CI, but ruby isn't working the way I expect it to.

It looks like Travis CI is properly running my bundle install, but the ruby gems can't be found by ruby immediately afterwards.  Here's the Travis log:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [x86_64-darwin13.1.0]
$ rvm --version
rvm 1.25.33 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
$ bundle --version
Bundler version 1.7.4

[... snip ...]


$ bundle install --jobs=3 --retry=3 --deployment
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Installing colorize 0.7.2
Installing json 1.8.1
Using bundler 1.7.4
Installing dnssd 2.0
Your bundle is complete!
It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
$ cat Gemfile.lock
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    colorize (0.7.2)
    dnssd (2.0)
    json (1.8.1)
PLATFORMS
  ruby
DEPENDENCIES
  colorize
  dnssd
  json
The command "cat Gemfile.lock" exited with 0.
$ ruby -e "require 'colorize'"
/Users/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- colorize (LoadError)
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
The command "ruby -e "require 'colorize'"" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

The `.travis.yml` file is simple for now:

```
language: objective-c
script:
  - cat Gemfile.lock
  - bundle env
  - ruby -e "require 'colorize'"
```

I assume that I'm making a simple mistake (possibly a pure-ruby mistake) but I can't see it.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Bundler doesn't make stuff magically available; you need to `require 'bundler/setup'` in your script to get Bundler to set up your load path.

Comment: That makes sense, but now I'm wondering what's happening on my local machine that makes it work there.  Could it be that `gem install` is different than `bundle install`?

Comment: `gem install` is different than `bundle install`, yes.

Comment: Interesting.  I had assumed that it was similar to `pip install` for Python, where it _does_ make things magically available.  I'll do some more research here, but I may ask you to convert your comment to an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: The difference is that Bundler can install things outside of the normal load paths, while pip will always install them into the standard load path. Requiring bundler/setup lets bundler massage your load paths to include the paths to the gems it installed for you. `gem install` is analogous to `pip install`, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bundler doesn't make stuff magically available; you need to `require 'bundler/setup'` in your script to get Bundler to set up your load path.

Bundler will install your gems to whatever path you want, but those gems aren't necessarily going to be in your Ruby load path, so `require` won't necessarily find them. You can get Bundler to alter your load paths to point to your installed bundle's gems via `require 'bundler/setup'` before using any other gems. This does require that bundler be available in your load path already, which is usually accomplished via `gem install bundler`. Travis comes with it preinstalled, so you don't need to do anything special to use it.

Comment: Your edit anticipated the comment I was about to leave :) Thanks

Comment: This worked!  `sudo gem update --system` and locally running `bundle install --deployment` helped too.